# How to change color in Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"; 

const useStayles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  textField: {
    color: "#4caf50",
  },
}));


<TextField
   label="Username*"
   **color="#4caf50"**
   fullWidth
   className={classes.textField}
            />
```

I what to change color to green, in bootstrap it is success, but i do not know how to add green color on textfield i try with useStayles but it does not work

Comment: Look for an `InputProps` prop

Answer (score 0):

You can have customized `TextField` like this:

```
const StyledTextField = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    margin: theme.spacing(2),
    width: 300,
    "& .MuiInput-underline": {
      color: "green",
      height: 60,
    },
    "& .MuiFormLabel-root": {
      color: theme.palette.secondary.main
    }
  }
}))(TextField);
```

Then just call your component with:

```
<StyledTextField />
```

Please remember to import `withStyles` and `TextField`:

```
import {TextField,withStyles} from "@material-ui/core/"
```

More info here: https://gist.github.com/Jon20111/84b17c484fcb6f50c768271124462dde#file-textfield-customization